# Unity animation is too fast when exporting from Blender

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, blender

I'm trying to export the tree animation I made in Blender with the Sapling Tree Gen plugin to Unity. In Blender everything is normal, but when I play the animation in Unity it's too fast. I already tried locking the Unity framerate to 30, but it doesn't change. Is there a way to slow down the animation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

first make sure you have made an animator component for your object(tree), then create an **animator controller** in your assets folder and open it, then add the default animation  from your imported object to your animation controller (it should be in your assets folder) and at last, by clicking on your default animation in animator controller you have access to speed and other properties related to your object.

Comment: I tried, but the animation is too fast also at 0.001 speed.